# Не работает часть кода в jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть файл, в котором я вызываю функции. Часть из них не работает. Но если нерабочую функцию перенести в другое место этого файла, она начинает работать. Понимаю, что дело скорее всего в синтаксисе, но ошибку найти не могу. Надеюсь на помощь.
Содержимое файла:

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".mapopen").click(function() {
      $(".mapblock").toggle();
      $(".viewsr").hide();
    });
    $(".close").click(function() {
      $(".mapblock").hide();
    });
    $("#closform").click(function() {
      $(".oformlenie").hide();
    });
    $(".cartt button").click(function() {
      $(".oformlenie").show();
    });

    $(".viewopen").click(function() {
      $(".viewsr").toggle();
      $(".mapblock").hide();
    });
    $(".prim").click(function() {
      $(".cbox").toggle();
    });
    $(".viewclose").click(function() {
      $(".viewsr").hide();
    });

    $.ionTabs("#tabs_1, #tabs_2, #tabs_3, #tabs_4, #otzivi", {
      type: "none"
    });
    $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
      auto: true, // Boolean: Animate automatically, true or false
      speed: 500, // Integer: Speed of the transition, in milliseconds
      timeout: 4000, // Integer: Time between slide transitions, in milliseconds
      pager: true, // Boolean: Show pager, true or false
      nav: false, // Boolean: Show navigation, true or false
      random: false, // Boolean: Randomize the order of the slides, true or false
      pause: false, // Boolean: Pause on hover, true or false
      pauseControls: true, // Boolean: Pause when hovering controls, true or false
      prevText: "", // String: Text for the "previous" button
      nextText: "", // String: Text for the "next" button
      maxwidth: "", // Integer: Max-width of the slideshow, in pixels
      navContainer: "", // Selector: Where controls should be appended to, default is after the 'ul'
      manualControls: "", // Selector: Declare custom pager navigation
      namespace: "rslides", // String: Change the default namespace used
      before: function() {}, // Function: Before callback
      after: function() {} // Function: After callback
    });
    $(".rslides2, .rslides3, .rslides4, .rslides5, .rslides6, .rslides7, .c1").responsiveSlides({
      auto: true,
      nav: true,
      prevText: "", // String: Text for the "previous" button
      nextText: ""
    });
    $('.crsl-items').carousel({
      speed: 1000,
      autoRotate: 6000,
      visible: 4,
      carousel: true
    });

    $(".boxvideo").fitVids();

    $('select').styler({
      selectSmartPositioning: '-1'
    });


    $('.slide__link').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();


      var $this = $(this),
        item = $this.closest('.slide__item'),
        wrap = $this.closest('.slideShow'),
        gap = wrap.find('.slide__gap'),
        itemPath = $this.find('img').attr('src'),
        dur = 500;

      if (!item.hasClass('activSl')) {
        item.addClass('.activSl').siblings().removeClass('activSl');
        gap.find('img').fadeOut(dur, function() {
          $(this).attr('src', itemPath).fadeIn(dur);
        });
      }

    });

    //Галерея товара

  });

  $(window).load(function() {

  })
```

При таком расположении

```
  $(".boxvideo").fitVids();

    $('select').styler({
      selectSmartPositioning: '-1'
    });
```

Не работает последняя функция.

Comment: $('select').styler({
      selectSmartPositioning: '-1'
    });

Comment: Или     $(".boxvideo").fitVids(); , в зависимости от расположения.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего ты подписываешься на родительские элементы и из-за всплытия обрабатываешь одно и то же событие несколько раз. Добавь каких-нибудь `console.log` в обработчики и проверь, где вызывается что-то лишнее.

А ещё `$('select')` выглядит подозрительно общим селектором.

Comment: Select общий, да. Но даже если я его задаю через класс, он не работает.